# Android, setonclicklistner to dynamically generated array of textviews

Tags: android, textview

I have a dynamically generated array of textviews

```
for(int i = 0; i < blog_link_counter; i++) {
textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
textViewArray[i].setText(Html.fromHtml(array_blog_text[i]+"<br>"));
textViewArray[i].setId(i);
textViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(this);
((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(textViewArray[i]);
}
```

Now i have an Activity, where there are a number of textviews. I need to add the onclick listner functionalities to all of the textviews.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

I added the onclicklistner in the java file.After that i implemented the onclicklistner interface

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

```
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.    <--  ?
    }

}}
```

How can i match as to which Textview id it's been refering to?

Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call [`setOnClickListener(OnClickListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) then on each of your `TextView`s.

```
for(int i = 0; i < blog_link_counter; i++) {
    textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
    textViewArray[i].setText(Html.fromHtml(array_blog_text[i]+"<br>"));
    textViewArray[i].setId(i);
    textViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(listener);
    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(textViewArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

don't have to use R.id.xxx, simply use the same numbers that you used in your loop:

```
switch(v.getId())
{
case 0:
case 1:
//etc
}
```