# setonclicklistner to dynamically generated array of textviews

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I have a dynamically generated array of textviews

```
for(int i = 0; i < blog_link_counter; i++) {
textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
textViewArray[i].setText(Html.fromHtml(array_blog_text[i]+"<br>"));
textViewArray[i].setId(i);
textViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(this);
((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(textViewArray[i]);
}
```

Now i have an Activity, where there are a number of textviews. I need to add the onclick listner functionalities to all of the textviews.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/info"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

I added the onclicklistner in the java file.After that i implemented the onclicklistner interface

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.    <--  ?
}

}}
```

How can i match as to which Textview id it's been refering to? I mean if the id were static i could do it like R.id.idfromxmlfile, but in this case what should i do?

Please Help

Comment: Why you repeat the question?? You post the question from another account earlier.

Comment: You asked this question 33 minutes ago (and I already answered it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480653/android-setonclicklistner-to-dynamically-generated-array-of-textviews/15480703#15480703 )

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to use `R.id.xxx`, simply use the same numbers that you used in your loop:

```
switch(v.getId())
{
case 0:
case 1:
//etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The View.setTag() function is more appropriate for this. Set the tag instead of setting the id

```
// Use .setTag
textViewArray[i].setTag(new Integer(i));
```

Than, you can retrieve the view by calling the .getTag()

```
Integer tag = (Integer) v.getTag();
switch(tag)
{
case 0:
case ...:
case blog_link_counter - 1:
}
```

Comment: Uh, how is this more appropriate? It does exactly the same thing, except it misuses the tag feature.